# Unit testing value of Observable returned from service (using async pipe)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

Running Angular/Jasmine/Karma, I have a component that consumes a service to set the value of an Observable 'items' array.  I display this using an async pipe.  Works great.

Now, I'm trying to set up a unit test and got it to pass, but I'm not sure I'm correctly verifying that the 'items' array is getting the correct value.

Here is the relevant component .html and .ts :

```js
export class ViperDashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    items: Observable<DashboardItem[]>;

    constructor(private dashboardService: ViperDashboardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.dashboardService.getDashboardItems();
    }
}
```

```html
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
            <h3>{{item.value}}</h3>
            <p>{{item.detail}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And my component.spec.ts:

```js
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ViperDashboardComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        viperDashboardService =        
  fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ViperDashboardService);

        mockItems = [
            { key: 'item1', value: 'item 1', detail: 'This is item 1' },
            { key: 'item2', value: 'item 2', detail: 'This is item 2' },
            { key: 'item3', value: 'item 3', detail: 'This is item 3' }
        ];

        spy = spyOn(viperDashboardService, 'getDashboardItems')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of<DashboardItem[]>(mockItems));

    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should call getDashboardItems after component initialzed', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(spy.calls.any()).toBe(true, 'getDashboardItems should be called');
    });

    it('should show the dashboard after component initialized', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.items).toEqual(Observable.of(mockItems));
    });
```

Specifically, I'd like to know:

1) I started off creating an async "it" test, but was surprised when that didn't work.  Why does a synchronous test work when I'm working with async data streams?

2) When I check the equivalence of component.items to the Observable.of(mockItems), am I really testing that the values are equal?  Or am I just testing that they are both Observables?  Is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need an async test yet because your service returns an observable immediately (as it should - the real value comes later). The async pipe in the template is what gets the real value later on. So right now your tests are just testing the synchronous portion of the code. Later on you'll probably need an async test if you test the that the template renders the items.

Comment: So yes you're essentially just testing that you're getting back an observable. My guess is that `expect(component.items).toEqual(Observable.of(mockItems));` passes because even though `Observable.of(mockItems));` is a different object reference then the observable returned by your mock, all of the properties might be equal so the objects are considered equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @FrankModica. Ok, this is what I was afraid of. So, is there no way to test that the Observable will eventually return the correct data? Or is the only solution to test the template renders it, as you suggest above? I can do that, but it seems like it's not testing in isolation.  If my test fails, I wouldn't know if I have a problem with the component logic or with the template, if you see what I mean.

Comment: You could probably avoid testing the template by not using an `async` filter. Instead you could subscribe to the observable in the component, and pull out the items there. Then you could just search around for how to test the return value of an async observable.

Comment: I had considered that, but I really like using the async pipe.  It seems to make the code a lot cleaner.  I wonder if I could instead pull the value in this way:  `component.items.toPromise().then(result => {
            expect(result).toEqual(mockItems);
        });`

Comment: You could do it that way. But you wouldn't be proving that the code (template in this case) actually unwraps the promise. Also, this is really minor but why convert it to a promise in the test instead of subscribing? Is one easier to test than the other?

Comment: I see your point.  And with respect to the promise - you are right!  I was a bit lazy, and couldn't remember the .map/subscribe syntax off the top of my head.  If you'd care to summarize as an answer I will accept.

Comment: I think a better answer has just been provided :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Angular provides the utilities for testing asynchronous values. You can use the [`async` utility with the `fixture.whenStable`](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-async-function-in-it) method or the [`fakeAsync` utility with the `tick()` function](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-fakeasync-function). Then using the `DebugElement`, you can actually query your template to be sure the values are getting loaded correctly.

Both methods for testing will work.

**Using the `async` utility with `whenStable`:**

Keep your setup the same, you're good to go there. You'll need to add some code to get ahold of the list's debug element. In your `beforeEach`:

```
const list = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('list-group'));
```

Then you can dig in to that list and get individual items. I won't go too far into how to use `DebugElement` because that's outside the scope of this question. Learn more here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#componentfixture-debugelement-and-querybycss.

Then in your unit test:

```
 it('should get the dashboard items when initialized', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => { // wait for your async data
          fixture.detectChanges(); // refresh your fake template
          /* 
             now here you can check the debug element for your list 
             and see that the items in that list correctly represent 
             your mock data 
             e.g. expect(listItem1Header.textContent).toEqual('list item 1');
           */
        }
    }));
```

**Using the `fakeAsync` utility with `tick`:**

```
it('should get the dashboard items when initialized', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        tick(); // wait for async data
        fixture.detectChanges(); // refresh fake template
        /* 
           now here you can check the debug element for your list 
           and see that the items in that list correctly represent 
          your mock data 
           e.g. expect(listItem1Header.textContent).toEqual('list item 1');
        */
}));
```

So in summary, do not remove the `async` pipe from your template just to make testing easier. The `async` pipe is a great utility and does a lot of clean up for you, plus the Angular team has provided some very useful testing utilites for this exact use-case. Hopefully one of the techniques above works. It sounds like using `DebugElement` and one of the aforementioned utilities will help you lots :)

Comment: Best practice is that you should get your data in ngOnInit(), so you have to create a mock for testing and in beforeEach() of the describe() you must add a spyOn(component, 'methodToGetData').and.returnValue(of(mock)), to catch service call, and have a nice mock returned instead of macking the real call.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package for testing observables [`jasmine-marbles`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-marbles)
With it you can write test like this:

```ts
...
spy = spyOn(viperDashboardService, 'getDashboardItems')
            .and.returnValue(cold('-r|', { r: mockItems }));
...
it('should show the dashboard after component initialized', () => {
        const items$ = cold('-r|', { r: mockItems });
        expect(component.items).toBeObservable(items$);
    });
```

But probably it is not the best example - I normally do use this package to test chains of observables. For example if I have service that do inside some `.map()`ing with input observable - I can mock original observable and then create a new one and compare with service results.

Also neither `async` nor `fakeAsync` will work with time dependent observable operations, but with `jasmine-marbles` you can inject test scheduler into them and it will work like a charm and without any timeouts - instantly! [Here](https://gist.github.com/pavel-agarkov/9e7badefd14b725ca7867a25774d7a0e) I have an example how to inject a test scheduler.